# I can't affect image size with css but I can in regards to it's position

Tags: html, css

for some flipping reason I can't control the height of width of my image

```
.pop_image{
  top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position:absolute;  
 }
```

the html

```
    <ul class="pop_image"><a href ="#"><img src="1.jpg"></a></ul>
```

Comment: **Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you mean *can't*? As it stands your question makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Do you really need `ul` here if there are no `li` in it? Probably `div` will be more suitable? `ul` without `li` is incorrect markup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To controll the size of the image, you need to address the image on the CSS:

```
.pop_image img { 
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS will determine the size of the `<ul>` list, not your image.
Try the following instead:

```
.pop_image img {
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a `display: block;` in `.pop_image` class even if the ul is normaly a block...